# Uncaught Argument Count error when setting up MongoDB in Codeception for PHP 7.2

Tags: php, mongodb, codeception

I'm trying to set up MongoDB as a database source in PHP 7.2 for Codeception. I set up the config in `codeception.yml`:

```
modules:
    config:
        MongoDb:
            dsn: 'mongodb://##.##.##.##:27017/test_data'
            user: 'root'
            password: '###'
            dump_type: MongoDb::DUMP_TYPE_JS
            dump: 'tests/_data/name.json'
            populate: true
            cleanup: false
            enabled:
                - Codeception\Lib\Driver\MongoDb
```

But when I run my tests, I get this error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function Codeception\Lib\Driver\MongoDb::__construct(), 2 passed and exactly 3 expected in /FOLDER/vendor/codeception/codeception/src/Codeception/Lib/Driver/MongoDb.php:97
Stack trace:
#0 [internal function]: Codeception\Lib\Driver\MongoDb->__construct(Object(Codeception\Lib\ModuleContainer), Array)
#1 /FOLDER/vendor/codeception/codeception/src/Codeception/Lib/Di.php(84): ReflectionClass->newInstanceArgs(Array)
#2 /FOLDER/vendor/codeception/codeception/src/Codeception/Lib/ModuleContainer.php(92): Codeception\Lib\Di->instantiate('Codeception\\Lib...', Array, false)
#3 /FOLDER/vendor/codeception/codeception/src/Codeception/SuiteManager.php(67): Codeception\Lib\ModuleContainer->create('Codeception\\Lib...')
#4 /FOLDER/vendor/codeception/codeception/src/Codeception/Codecept.php(186): Codeception\SuiteManager->__construct(Object(Sym in /FOLDER/vendor/codeception/codeception/src/Codeception/Lib/Driver/MongoDb.php on line 97
```

To get rid of the argument error, I temporarily changed the function definition to read:

```
public function __construct($dsn, $user, $password = '') { ... }
```

For some reason, it is passing in the number `1` to both `$dsn` and `$user`. Using `print_r`, I can see that there is a `Codeception\Lib\ModuleContainer` Object, and that it has a `['config']['MongoDb']` entry with the correct configuration. But this information isn't being loaded.

For reference, in my `codeception.yml` file, I've tried following the initial directions they give, and have tried not putting the `enabled` configuration option in there. I've also added `database: admin` to the MongoDb config. The only time I even got to the error portion was with `enabled` set. Otherwise I just get an authorization failed error for Mongo.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you enabled not MongoDb module, but MongoDb driver which is not a module.

Correct configuration is:

```
modules:
    config:
        MongoDb:
            dsn: 'mongodb://##.##.##.##:27017/test_data'
            user: 'root'
            password: '###'
            dump_type: MongoDb::DUMP_TYPE_JS
            dump: 'tests/_data/name.json'
            populate: true
            cleanup: false
    enabled:
        - MongoDb
```

Comment: I changed it to what you had and I still end up with the same error: `Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function Codeception\Lib\Driver\MongoDb::__construct(), 2 passed and exactly 3 expected in /FOLDER/vendor/codeception/codeception/src/Codeception/Lib/Driver/MongoDb.php:97`

Comment: Please run codeception with -vvv flag and provide a stacktrace.